# Selenium - Drag and Drop issue in Chrome

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

there is a site to practice: http://the-internet.herokuapp.com/drag_and_drop

if tried to permove a simple drag and drop action in Chrome. But nothing happens (actually only one column has been selected and then nothing)

I've located elements like this

```
By COLUMN_A_LOCATOR = By.xpath("//*/header[contains(text(),'A')]/..");
By COLUMN_B_LOCATOR = By.xpath("//*/header[contains(text(),'B')]/..");
```

and tried to perform drag and drop like this

```
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);

actions.clickAndHold(driver.findElement(COLUMN_B_LOCATOR)).moveToElement(driver.findElement(COLUMN_A_LOCATOR)).release().perform();
```

and like this

```
actions.dragAndDrop(driver.findElement(COLUMN_B_LOCATOR),driver.findElement(COLUMN_A_LOCATOR)).perform();
```

and nothing. Also I've noticed that columns classNames are dynamic on this website maybe this is the reason I can't drag and drop?

also wound this https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/3269 - maybe this is still a thing

Comment: What is the chrome version you are using? Experienced broken drag-n-drop in chrome 80. But fixed in latest

Comment: Im using 81.0.4044.122

Answer (score 1):

```
public void move_elements(WebElement source,WebElement target) throws InterruptedException
    {

        final String java_script =
                "var src=arguments[0],tgt=arguments[1];var dataTransfer={dropEffe" +
                                "ct:'',effectAllowed:'all',files:[],items:{},types:[],setData:fun" +
                                "ction(format,data){this.items[format]=data;this.types.append(for" +
                                "mat);},getData:function(format){return this.items[format];},clea" +
                                "rData:function(format){}};var emit=function(event,target){var ev" +
                                "t=document.createEvent('Event');evt.initEvent(event,true,false);" +
                                "evt.dataTransfer=dataTransfer;target.dispatchEvent(evt);};emit('" +
                                "dragstart',src);emit('dragenter',tgt);emit('dragover',tgt);emit(" +
                                "'drop',tgt);emit('dragend',src);";

                        ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript(java_script, source, target);

    }
```

use javascript drag and drop it will work. But I do not know why action class doesn't work on that.

Comment: I tried to run the script in the browser but got `TypeError: this.types.append is not a function`. Any ideas?

Comment: this solution works

>But I do not know why action class doesn't work on that.
seems like issue in html5 and selenium

Comment: try removing "+" ......................                                     

"var src=arguments[0],tgt=arguments[1];var dataTransfer={dropEffe" +
                                "ct:''
...................
as "var src=arguments[0],tgt=arguments[1];var dataTransfer={dropEffect:'